# Why is the subsurf modifier not creating smooth geometry?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

I'm totally new to Blender. Excuse me, if my problem is dumb.

I'm trying to model something rather simple from a mesh. A handle. When I try to merge vertices of those two highlighted faces, I'm getting pretty awful result with subsurf modifier. The same thing happens, when I snap one face to another and then remove doubles. I guess the root of the problem is something simple, but can't figure it out.

[image: Highlighted faces I want to merge]

And the result:

[image: Bad result with subsurf modifier]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scale along the `Y` axis to `0` (<kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd>), delete the faces (<kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces*), and remove doubles (<kbd>W</kbd> *> Remove Doubles*). The issue you are having is there are internal faces, if you just remove the doubles, then there is still a face inside of the mesh, which leads to this weird artifact.

Comment: Now I get it. I forgot about those faces. Thanks a lot!